# What's the best way to resolve a filepath?

Tags: c++, windows, path

I've got a series of filepaths that look something like this:

- C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalSystemNetworkRestricted
- C:\Windows\System32\svchost
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Steam\SteamService.exe /RunAsService
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Steam\SteamService.exe" /RunAsService

and I need to find these paths' actual locations. So, respectively, the above would be:

- C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
- C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Steam\SteamService.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Steam\SteamService.exe

What's the best way to go about doing this? Does windows have an API function to accomplish it? I essentially am trying to figure out what executable CreateProcess will call if I pass it that path.

Thanks!

Billy3

EDIT: This is the code I settled on for now:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>

namespace Path {

bool Exists(const std::wstring& path)
{
    DWORD result = GetFileAttributesW(path.c_str());
    return result != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES;
}

#define PATH_PREFIX_RESOLVE(path, prefix, environment) \
if (boost::algorithm::istarts_with(path, prefix)) { \
    ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(environment, buffer, MAX_PATH); \
    path.replace(0, (sizeof(prefix)/sizeof(wchar_t)) - 1, buffer); \
    if (Exists(path)) return path; \
}

std::wstring Resolve(std::wstring path)
{
    using namespace boost::algorithm;
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    trim(path);
    if (path.empty() || Exists(path)) return path;

    //Start by trying to see if we have a quoted path
    if (path[0] == L'"') {
        return std::wstring(path.begin() + 1, std::find(path.begin() + 1, path.end(), L'"'));
    }

    //Check for those nasty cases where the beginning of the path has no root
    PATH_PREFIX_RESOLVE(path, L"\\", L"");
    PATH_PREFIX_RESOLVE(path, L"?\?\\", L"");
    PATH_PREFIX_RESOLVE(path, L"\\?\\", L"");
    PATH_PREFIX_RESOLVE(path, L"globalroot\\", L"");
    PATH_PREFIX_RESOLVE(path, L"system32\\", L"%systemroot%\\System32\\");
    PATH_PREFIX_RESOLVE(path, L"systemroot\\", L"%systemroot%\\");

    static std::vector<std::wstring> pathExts;
    if (pathExts.empty()) {
        #define MAX_ENVVAR 32767
        wchar_t pathext[MAX_ENVVAR];
        DWORD length = GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"PATHEXT", pathext, MAX_ENVVAR);
        if (!length) WindowsApiException::ThrowFromLastError();
        split(pathExts, pathext, std::bind2nd(std::equal_to<wchar_t>(), L';'));
        pathExts.insert(pathExts.begin(), std::wstring());
    }
    std::wstring::iterator currentSpace = path.begin();
    do {
        currentSpace = std::find(currentSpace, path.end(), L' ');
        std::wstring currentPath(path.begin(), currentSpace);
        std::wstring::size_type currentPathLength = currentPath.size();
        typedef std::vector<std::wstring>::const_iterator ExtIteratorType;
        for(ExtIteratorType it = pathExts.begin(); it != pathExts.end(); it++) {
            currentPath.replace(currentPathLength, currentPath.size() - currentPathLength, *it);
            if (Exists(currentPath)) return currentPath;
        }
        if (currentSpace != path.end())
            currentSpace++;
    } while (currentSpace != path.end());

    return path;
}

}
```

Comment: Those aren't paths, those are command lines that happen to begin with paths.

Comment: @bmargulies: I suppose that's true -- I guess I need the path part of said commandlines then.

Comment: #3 is the big problem. how do you determine you're done with paths (and don't forget that half the time paths are specified with forward slashes) and into slash delimited parameters? At least with the quotation marks it's doable...

Comment: @MPelletier: That is the reason for the question. CreateProcess seems to be okay with these paths, though I for one would consider them malformed.

Comment: I feel your pain, but I don't know of an API outside the kernel that implements the rules that CreateProcess implements.

Comment: What's the name of the API in the kernel that implements it? (if any?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 4 should be relatively easy. If the path starts with a " character, just read until the next " and that's the path. With the others, it's slightly more tricky, but the way Windows does it is by simply breaking the command line into parts, and trying one at a time, so looking at #3, it breaks it up into an array like this:

```
["C:\Program", "Files", "(x86)\Common", "Files\Steam\SteamService.exe", "/RunAsService"]
```

Then it simply starts from the left-most element and looks for files:

1. C:\Program
2. C:\Program Files
3. C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
4. C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Stream\StreamService.exe
5. C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Steam\SteamService.exe /RunAsService

Each step, it checks whether a file with that name exists. If so, that's the one it chooses. It also tries appending ".exe" to the name. So in the first step, it checks whether there is a file called "C:\Program.exe" and if so, that's the first. If not, it moves to the second step and tries "C:\Program Files.exe". If that doesn't exist, it moves to the next one and so on.

There have been issues in the past with how this algorithm works, for example, [see here](http://www.securityfocus.com/columnists/301).

Comment: This can't be entirely correct -- I believe CreateProcess is parsing the PATHEXT environment variable. If I create a run key (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\\Runme = "C:\Program"`) and put an executable as C:\program.com, it is being executed at startup.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct. It will try C:\Program.exe, C:\Program.com, C:\Program.bat and so on - all the extenions from PATHEXT will be attempted.

Comment: Looks like I have to write it myself grr... hope I don't f*** it up! :P

Answer (score -1):

See the [Shell Path Handling Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559(VS.85).aspx) in shlwapi.h.
Your examples should make it with `::PathRemoveArgs(sPath)` followed by `::PathMatchSpec(sPath, _T("*.exe"))`.

Comment: Right he should also call ::PathUnquoteSpaces() :-)

Comment: You're also assuming the file is an EXE file which is not the case. Plus, something like `C:\Windows\System32\svchost -k something` is a valid path which needs to return `C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe` or `C:\Windows\System32\svchost.com` or whatever as specified by `%PATHEXT%`.